# TinyMCE paste function doesn't work

Tags: tinymce

I try to use copy/paste functions in the TinyMCE editor, but I've noticed that paste function doesn't work. I removed all plugins and retested this with "clean" TinyMCE, but paste still haven't work.You can see it in this simple example:
http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Wpfaab

1. Type the text
2. Click Edit-> Copy
3. Click Edit-> Paste
4. Nothing happens

How can I fix it?

Comment: I got the same problem - do you have any solution? In chrome nothing happens

Comment: I found solution only for IE:  
Open IE  --> Go to "Tools...",  "Internet Options"  --> Click "Security" Tab  ->> Click "Custom level..."  ->> Find "Allow Programmatic clipboard access"  ->> OK

Answer (score 1):

Paste works, all you need to do is to add the paste plugin to your tinymce config:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: "textarea",  // change this value according to your HTML
  plugins: "paste",
  menubar: "edit",
  toolbar: "paste"
});
```

Comment: I think it is browser setting issue, because in the IE it working fine now. In the FF I see this message: Your browser doesn't support direct access to the clipboard. In the Chrome/Opera - nothing happens

Comment: @DmitryP. What did you endup doing on this issue? Have you tried upgrading tinymce to latest version. New version can at least show a neat error message in Chrome also just like it does in FF.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to solve this is by removing the 'contextmenu' plugin.

Comment: contextmenu is a property, not a plugin. Also does not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [custom button](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/demo/custom-toolbar-button/) like so:

```
setup: (editor) => {
  editor.ui.registry.addButton('customPasteButton', {
     icon: 'paste',
     onAction: (_) => navigator.clipboard.readText().then((text) => editor.insertContent(text))
   });
}
```

Then add `customPasteButton` to the toolbar.

When the button is first clicked, the browser will request access to your clipboard.